# Not able to locate artifact in maven repository

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I am using maven version 3.6.1

- I want to download artifact in maven repository (elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.5.1).
  I am able to locate it at [maven-central-repository search](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-central-repository/)
- But while searching the repos given in [elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.5.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.5.1) which are Central and JCenter

[image] .

I am not able to locate the corresponding artifact in  [Central Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) as well as in [JCentre Repo](https://jcenter.bintray.com/)
[image]

So can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in these URLs - [center repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/) and [jcenter repo](https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/)