# Download artifact from maven repository when not connected to company VPN

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, vpn

In continuation of my previous question [not-able-to-locate-artifact-in-maven-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628658/not-able-to-locate-artifact-in-maven-repository), I am able to locate the artifact in maven repo thereby adding the corresponding URL of the artifact in pom.xml

[image]

I am still not able to download the artifact from the maven repository.

[image]

- Using my company provided maven settings.xml which uses my company repository, when I am not connected to VPN of my company and then do maven import it doesn't work with below error.

`Could not resolve dependencies for project com.indore:galaxy:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.4.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:pom:7.4.1 from/to nexus (http://nexus.dev.<my-company-name>.com/nexus/content/groups/public): nexus.dev.<my-company-name>.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known:`

[image]

So can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

**Edit 1**

As stated by @Opster Elasticsearch Ninja I have provided the mirror tag in my `maven settings.xml`

```
<mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://nexus.dev.<my-company>.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

And, Intellij maven settings is:

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @leopal I have updated my question, and mentioned the error.

Comment: @Bhavya, you can provide the `mirror` tag of your maven settings.xml?

Comment: @Bhavya also your intellij maven settings, is it using intelliJ bundled maven or your installed one ?

Comment: @Bhavya did you get a chance to look into this answer ?